# Cloud Scheduler suddenly giving "INVALID_ARGUMENT" error

Tags: function, google-cloud-platform, cloud, scheduler

I have a few functions deployed in "Cloud Functions." These functions have been running just fine for the past year while being scheduled with "Cloud Scheduler". I just made a single change to a string in the cloud function and redeployed it. The function runs perfectly when using the testing option, but suddenly the Cloud Scheduler will no longer trigger the function. It returns the error "INVALID_ARGUMENT." The other functions that have not been redeployed in the past few months continue to function normally through the scheduler. Only the redeployed function fails.

I have done just about everything I can think with permissions and other options. Did something change with the deployment of v1 functions that is blocking access from the scheduler?

I cannot even create a new function to be accessed by the scheduler. Even this gives the same error... I make something super simple that will print "hello world," set up the service account that accesses it. I then create a Scheduler to access it using OIDC and the same service account and I get the same "INVALID ARGUMENT" error. Meanwhile the scheduler is doing just fine running my other older functions perfectly fine using identical settings.

Any help would be appreciated, I am currently having to manually trigger the function!

Answer (score 3):

After 4 hours of pain, I figured it out. I have no idea what changed with V1 Cloud Functions in the past month or so, but when a function is redeployed it must have a newer version of Flask or Requests or some other library or restriction.

For the people who come along with this issue, you need to add to the headers in the cloud scheduler:

Name:Content-Type
Value:application/json

You also need to put a {} into the body field if you don't have anything in there.

This should fix the problem. Hopefully I save someone else some time!

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error, but my API is a get API. Do I still need to provide this header?