# Cloud Scheduler giving "INVALID_ARGUMENT" error to deploy Dataflow job (using flex template)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud, google-cloud-scheduler

I have a cloud scheduler which is supposed to deploy the dataflow job using the flex template. I have terraform changes to create cloud scheduler which creates a cloud scheduler job. However, when im trying to run the job it given error

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", "jobName":"projects/engineering-199721/locations/us-central1/jobs/dummy-batch-daily-job", "status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT", "targetType":"HTTP", "url":"https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/engineering-199721/locations/us-central1/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://inf_bigdata_dev15_temp_location/dataflow/templates/sample_batch_job_D3.1.7-47-g3c619"}
```

below is my tf code

```
  resource "google_cloud_scheduler_job" "dummy-batch_daily"
   {
  name = "dummy-batch-daily-job"
  schedule = "0 2 * * *"  # 2 am daily
  region = var.GCP_REGION
  time_zone = "America/Los_Angeles"
  
  http_target {
    http_method = "POST"
    uri = "https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/${var.GCP_PROJECT}/locations/${var.GCP_REGION}/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://xyz/dataflow/templates/sample_batch_job_D3.1.7-47-g3c619"

    oauth_token {
      service_account_email = "xyz@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
    
    body = base64encode(<<-EOT
    {
      "jobName": "dummy-batch",
      "parameters": {
        "project": "${var.GCP_PROJECT}",
        "deploymentName": "${var.INF_PURE_DEPLOYMENT}",
        "bigQueryProject": "${var.GCP_PROJECT}",
        "bigQueryTable": "${var.INF_BIGDATA_TELEMETRY_REPROCESS_BIGQUERY_TABLE}",
        "bigQueryDataset": "${var.INF_BIGDATA_BIGQUERY_DATASET}",
        "bigDataDisplayVersion": 1
      },
      "environment": {
        "subnetwork": "regions/${var.GCP_REGION}/subnetworks/${var.INF_BIGDATA_SUBNET}",
        "tempLocation": "${var.INF_BIGDATA_PIPELINE_TEMP_LOCATION}/dataflow",
        "numWorkers": ${var.INF_BIGDATA_START_NUM_WORKERS}
      }
    }
  EOT
    )
    headers = {
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

Did tried https://medium.com/@zhongchen/schedule-your-dataflow-batch-jobs-with-cloud-scheduler-8390e0e958e,
as well tried removing the 'parameters' block but still the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "INVALID\_ARGUMENT" error typically indicates that a request contains an invalid argument. Could you provide more information about the environment you're using and where the request is being made from? Additionally, the link you shared appears to be broken. Could you please provide a working link to the document you are following?Also, take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77084234/) .